# Building Luabind in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, lua, luabind

I'm having problems making Lua & Luabind work under Windows 7 using VS 2010. So far, I've downloaded LuaBinaries from http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net and Luabind from http://www.hci.iastate.edu/~rpavlik/doxygen/luabind/docs.html . I've set up my environment variables BOOST_ROOT and LUA_PATH accordingly in the Command Line as mentioned in Luabind's INSTALL file and I can't get past this error:

```
C:\lua\luabind>bjam stage
error: at Jamroot:41
error: *** Unable to determine Lua include directory.
```

If anyone has been able to build Luabind under Windows any hint is much appreciated! Even more, if anyone has been able to set up a VS 2010 C++ project with Lua & Luabind and is willing to share I'll be more than thankful!

Comment: Check that LUA_PATH exist in current* enviroment.

Comment: Already verified that it exists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hm... Very strange...
How I build luabind under MSVS2008Express.
I download lua5_1_4_Win32_dll8_lib.zip  (luabind jam-file not properly configured for lua 5.2 ), setup enviroment, build boost, build luabind.

Step by step:

- Download boost, luabinaries (5.1), luabind
- Build boost (I already have 1.46.1 and not rebuild it)
- Setup enviroment variable (right-click on My Computer->Properties->Advanced-> button "Environment Variables" for permanent variables, or use SET for local)
  In the command interpreter:

  `set BOOST_ROOT=g:\from_work\repo\Env\Boost`

  `set LUA_PATH=d:\test\sover\lua`
- Go to the `luabind` directory and run `bjam stage` (`bjam` must be in `PATH`), luabind was builded. I don't test it, just build.
  I hope this help.