# Unable to determine lua include directory

Tags: boost, lua, luabind, bjam

I am trying to install Luabind in my Windows 8 RP. This is what I have done so far.

- My Visual Studio is 2012 RC version.
- I have installed LuaforWindows 5.1.4
- I have downloaded luabind-0.9.1
- I have downloaded boost_1_51_0 that is needed by luabind
- I have installed BOOST successfully
- I have set the path for Bjam in my BOOST_ROOT Environment Variable
- I have set the path for Lua in LUA_PATH Environment Variable

Now when I try to run bjam in Luabind directory the following error shows up.

```
error: at Jamroot:41 error: 
*** Unable to determine Lua include directory.
```

I don't understand why Jamroot is having difficulty finding the path to Lua directory. I also tried including path in my PATH Environment Variable instead of just in LUA_PATH Environment Variable.

I have been searching this for three days straight now. I also tried following [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989319/building-luabind-in-windows) But it still did not help.

If anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong then please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the jamroot code for luabind-0.9.1 around line 41:

```
LUA_PATH = [ os.environ LUA_PATH ] ;

if ! $(LUA_PATH)
{
    errors.user-error "*** LUA_PATH must be set." ;
}

local includes = [ GLOB $(LUA_PATH)/include $(LUA_PATH)/src : lua.h ] ;

if ! $(includes)
{
    errors.user-error "*** Unable to determine Lua include directory." ;
}
```

It looks like you have the `LUA_PATH` environment variable set because you didn't get an error stating otherwise, but bjam can't find `lua.h` in your `%LUA_PATH%/include` or `%LUA_PATH%/src` folder.

I've had similar problems with `LUA_PATH` before and ended up copying the value of `LUA_DEV` into `LUA_PATH` temporarily to get some tools to work. Check your variables and then consider doing this value copy until you get luabind built.

---

Edit: I'm using an older version of Boost, but I would expect the build to work the same. Below are my environment variables as they were configured by the Lua installer. Note that `LUA_PATH` doesn't point to the `Lua\5.1` directory like I would have expected it to, hence my need to change it temporarily.

> LUA_PATH=;;C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1\lua\?.luac
>
> LUA_DEV=C:\Program Files\Lua\5.1

Comment: You know copying LUA_DEV values to LUA_PATH did solve the problem like you did. It's so strange. Thanks a million for helping me out. I was having a very hard time trying to figure this out. Endless search in vain. Thank you so much once again.